# How to get complete file name and path of file which is opened in java program?

Tags: java, swing, html-editor

i created an html editor and i want to get the file name & path of opened file in the JTextPane. any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post some sample code ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: *"i want to get the file name & path of opened file"*  Did you (or your code) not tell the `JEditorPane` what file to load?  Keep a reference to it!

Comment: file.getPath() method has solved my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you make use of the File chooser (the file picker), which seems quite likely for a code editor you could simply save the file path you receive as a result:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //At this point you can use: file.getName() to get your filename
            //You can also use file.getPath()
        } else {
            //Canceled opening
        }
    }
}
```

You could save the result of file.getName() and file.getPath() to a string that you would assign to your JTextPane later on.

For additional information on file choosers see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) which also explains this process in more detail.

Should you be working with File you can make use of the same functions which will provide the same information.

Comment: Thanks a lot... file.getName() and file.getPath() works for me...!